# ODBC, SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, Cursor type changed - happening on a Stored Procedure with a single SELECT

Tags: c++, sql, stored-procedures, odbc

I'm wondering whether anyone else has had this problem and how they resolved it?

Our application makes the follwoing ODBC call:

```
CString strCmd = "sprTestSingleSelect";
rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (UCHAR*)(LPCSTR)strCmd, SQL_NTS);
```

The call retruns `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`. By checking `SQLGetDiagRec` we see the message; Cursor type changed.

We found the following articles from Micrsoft;

1. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156500/en-us
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms130807.aspx

The stored procedure, `sprTestSingleSelect`, was created specifically to test what both articles hinted at - multiple selects cause the change.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sprTestSingleSelect
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM address
END
GO
```

However, even with this very simple (single SELECT) stored procedure, the cursor type is still being changed (from `SQL_CURSOR_KEYSET_DRIVEN` to `SQL_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY`).

We need to cursor type to stay at `SQL_CURSOR_KEYSET_DRIVEN`, as later on in the application we are calling `SQLFetchScroll(hstmt, SQL_FETCH_LAST, 0);`, which is falling because of the incorrect cursor type.

Does anyone have an idea of what we might be doing wrong or what is going wrong?

We are using MS SQL Server 2008R2

Our application is written in C++ (using Visual Studio 10 Premium)

Answer (score 1):

We've managed to get the above test working, however the solution is not very satisfactory.

When the store procedure **only** contains a single `SELECT` statement and nothing else it works. So to get it working all we had to do was remove the statement `SET NOCOUNT ON;`. As a side note, we tested setting NOCOUNT to OFF which also didn't work - removing the statement alltogether is what was required.

This seems to make using stored procedures to return data (result sets) rather useless!

If anyone has another (better) solution, we'd love to hear it...